# Thinking sphinx string date attribute

Tags: sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I have a column 'value' of type TEXT. It can contain regular text, and also dates in string format. I index the column with `indexes value`. Can I also add an attribute that converts this column to an integer? I tried both of the following:

```
has "str_to_date(model.value, '%Y-%m-%d')", as: :value_as_date, type: :integer
has "CONVERT(model.value, DATETIME)", as: :value_as_date, type: :integer
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two approaches here... Sphinx has a timestamp (datetime) data type for attributes, so you could use that:

```
has "CONVERT(model.value, DATETIME)", as: :value_as_date, type: :timestamp
```

Or, it may be better to use an integer representing the date (because it sounds like you don't ned the time aspect) by extracting the date from the string, and then converting the %Y%m%d value to an integer (note, no hyphens in the date format).

```
has "... more complex SQL snippet ...", as: :value_as_date, type: :integer
```

In that situation, you'd then need to convert any dates for filters to integers of the same format as well.

All of this aside: you'll want to have something in your SQL snippets that handles situations where your `value` column holds something *other* than a date. Or perhaps it's worth pulling those date values out into a separate column to have more consistent data? (Easy to suggest without knowing the full context of your app, I know.)

Comment: Ok, your first solution works because the type is 'timestamp' instead of 'integer'. Why doesn't integer work in that case?

Comment: If you want it to be an integer, you've got to have the SQL provide an integer :)

Comment: Right. I thought Sphinx always translated it to integer... Thanks.

Comment: That's a fair point... it kinda does. I'd forgotten it does expect a timestamp integer (number of seconds since 1st Jan 1970), but the data type when configuring is still 'timestamp' rather than 'integer'.